# Tournament contained in vertex transitive tournament

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory

Is it true that every finite tournament is contained in some finite [vertex-transitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex-transitive_graph) tournament? If not, is it known which tournaments satisfy this property? This seems like a basic question, but I have not been able to find a relevant reference.

In a comment @bof claims that every finite tournament is contained in some finite cyclic tournament. Why is that?

Comment: do you require your tournaments to be finite?

Answer (score 3):

bof got it right in a comment; here are the details. Let $T$ be a tournament with $n$ vertices. Label the vertices $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ in any way such that the $\binom n2$ values $|v_i-v_j|$ are distinct. Example: $v_i=2^i$. Now, for any odd (*per bof*) $N$ greater than twice the largest label, make a cyclic tournament where for each $1\le i,j\le n$ and $0\le k\lt N$ the edge from $k$ to $k+v_j-v_i \pmod N$ has the same direction as the edge from $i$ to $j$ has in $T$.

<s>The next question is whether the transitive tournament must sometimes be exponentially larger than $T$. I'm guessing yes.</s> *As bof notes in comment this is not so.*

Regarding Andreas' answer, note that my answer is only for the finite case, though maybe it works in the countable case too.

Comment: My answer is also about finite tournaments, but it asks for more, namely the property that all partially defined automorphisms can be extended. The resulting tournament would be also edge-transitive etc.

Comment: I don't know anything about uncountable tournaments, but your construction seems to work fine in the countable case. In fact there is **one** vertex-transitive countable tournament which contains a copy of every countable tournament. Namely, the random countable tournament contains a copy of every countable tournament, so it suffices to embed the random tournament in an "infinite cyclic tournament".

Comment: In this construction, you can take $N=O(n^2)$, see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golomb_ruler#Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Tur%C3%A1n_construction .

Answer (score 2):

It was shown in [Bernhard Herwig and Daniel Lascar, Extending partial automorphisms
and the profinite topology on free groups, Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 352 (2000), 1985-2021] that every finite tournament is contained in a finite tournament with the extension property for partial automorphisms if and only a certain question about the profinite topology of the free group has a positive answer. The questions asks if it is equivalent that a finitely generated subgroup $H$ of a free group is closed in the odd-topology (arising from all quotients of odd order) and that the implication $a^2 \in H \Rightarrow a \in H$ holds.

In particular, this (slightly stronger assertion than just vertex transitivity) is an open problem.

Comment: it looks much stronger assertion than vertex transitivity (to say the least, it implies the edge transitivity, yes?)